# How to convert a missing data to a NaN value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert missing data in an xls file to a dataframe of Nan values.

```
New list=energy.where(energy['Energy Supply']>=0)
```

I got:

> the operator >= can't be used between strings and integer.

My data type is numeric apart from the missing data.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.

Comment: Problem is column filled by strings, first is necessary convert to numeric.

Comment: How did you solve your problem? You should post feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.loc` for indexing:

```
energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply']>=0,:]
```

Use of `:` to show all columns is optional. Following should also work:

```
energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply']>=0]
```

Above will not include any missing values.

To detect strings, use:

```
energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: False if isinstance(x,str) else x>=0)
```

To replace all strings with NaN:

```
energy['Energy Supply'].loc[energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))] = numpy.nan
```

Also, `New` keyword is not used in Python.

Another point, since `list` is a keyword in Python, it should not be used as a variable. Use `lst` or `mylist` etc.